# My Available RAM Memory Is Lower Than Usual

Tags: windows-10, memory

My pc has been crashing lately and my available ram has been down to 10gb (i have 2x 8gb ram) still while writing this it is down to 9.5 getting up to 9.6 people said my ram could be damaged but they both are not 8gb when i try them separately. What shall i do my games are crashing which might be the cause i get not enough ram while watching twitch streams i am trying not to burn my pc .

I tried everything i know but couldnt come up with a solution

[image]

Comment: What makes you draw the conclusions that 1) 10GB free RAM is 'not enough' & 2) that this has any connection to your crashing?

Comment: First open resmon to check hardware reserved memory, then run mdsched to test the memory modules, I think your RAM modules have been damaged but first we need to verify it, if they are damaged just buy new ones.

Comment: i added a picture thank you for responding i might have caused the issue since it has 7gb used and 9gb available

Comment: tetsujin it is because when my game kept crashing the support team told me that it could cause the issue and since i have 16 gb rams 10 is not enough for gaming

Comment: 1. [optimize windows 10 for gaming](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/optimize-windows-10-gaming/) 2. clean up autostart  3. disable unnecessary win 10 services    4. uninstall unused software   5. see if issue persists and report back

Comment: Since a memory module is either functional or not functional the description of your problem does not make sense.  A 8 GB will be detected as 8 GB, your system will show you have a percentage of that memory free and the rest will be used to run applications.  **It's impossible for your system to detect only, as an example, only 7 GB out of 8 GB module.**  Your screenshot clearly indicates your system is detecting 16 GB.  Adding additional memory will not solve your applications from crashing.  You have several background applications that could easily be closed.

Comment: i will be working on closing those but still i am facing another weird problem where every game i have reinstalls itself

Answer (score 0):

You have 16 GB of ram, of which 6 GB is in use, leaving 10 GB of free RAM.

This is plenty of RAM for ANY game.

That said, RAM is not going to be an issue no matter how much you have unless the game speficically programs in a check and halt the game if too little ram is installed. The reason for this is, once you have insuficient ram, the game will simply use the SWAP file to get access to more RAM. This makes it a slow process, so the game's performance will be slower, but it will not lead to a crash.

Support claiming it must be RAM is just saying that you are dealing with someone who is not a tech enthusiast, and doesn't know the answer.

I have 16 GB of ram in my pc as well and I can literally play every game, and I have some memory intensive programs running in the background. My available free ram hovers around 3 GB most of the time too. So basically, when I run out of RAM most of those running apps will be moved to swap file to get free ram.

So the question here is not why you have this little ram, because seriously you don't. The question becomes, why is my game crashing.

I would therefor want to ask you to consider this question solved and open a new question specifically about troubleshooting why your game is crashing. We need to know, what game(s) are you playing, does it happen to many games? What errors do you get, can you reproduce the crashing consistently, and anything else you tried that may be useful to finding the root cause.

Comment: There are some AAA games on the market that require more than 16 GB.  However, those applications, wouldn't even start if your system didn't meet the requirements to run it.  In the screenshot you provided you have more than 8 Gb available for any application that wants it.

Comment: @Ramhound Please name me one game that absolutely won't run if you have 16GB RAM. My research yields none. For example, I would expect GTA5, a game that is massive would require 16GB, but even that game will run fine with just 4GB RAM. Another example: MS Flight Sim only requires 8GB of RAM. A new AAA game: CyperPunk 2077 has minimum 8GB requirements.